# Android: Different Drag and Drop Actions onLongClick and onTouch

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, ontouchlistener, onlongclicklistener, motionevent

I want to implement two different Drag and Drop interactions with one Button. If the user clicks long on the Button, he can move the button. This is no Problem, I implemented `OnLongClickListener`:

```
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    ClipData dragData = ClipData.newPlainText(
            AbstractFragment.BUTTON_ID_TAG, "" + v.getId());
    DragShadowBuilder shadow = new DragShadowBuilder(v);
    v.startDrag(dragData, shadow, null, 0);
    return true;
}
```

If the user touches the Button and drags immediately he can draw a line from this button to another. I think I have to implement the `OnTouchListener` interface, but I'm not sure about the condition to recognize this userinteraction. Which `MotionEvent` or rather which combination of `MotionEvent`s do I need to recognize this input.

I hope you can give me some hints!

grtz warci

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onClick", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ClipData dragData = ClipData.newPlainText(
                AbstractFragment.BUTTON_ID_TAG, "" + v.getId());
        DragShadowBuilder shadow = new CanvasDragShadow(v);
        v.startDrag(dragData, shadow, null, 0);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I added this Method, and it works. Maybe it's necessary to check the History of `MotionEvent`s to have a better user-experience.